# Generate 10 balls in tkinter canvas

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, drawing, tkinter-canvas

Ok guys.
I am trying to generate 10 balls of random color in Tkinter canvas when I click the generate button. 
Program works, and random color choice works for the ball, but I only get one ball generated at a time. 
Every time I click the button it randomly moves the ball around, but all I want is 10 balls in 10 random positions at a time. I am using Python 3.4 on a Linux box. 
This is a code I've got:

```
from tkinter import *
import random # to generate random balls

colors = ["red", "blue", "purple", "green", "violet", "black"]

class RandomBalls:
    """
    Boilerplate code for window in Tkinter
    window = Tk()
    window.title("Random title")
    window.mainloop()
    """


    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initialize the window and add two frames, one with button, and another one with
        canvas
        :return:
        """

        window = Tk()
        window.title("Random balls")

        # A canvas frame
        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        self.canvas = Canvas(frame1, width = 200, height = 300, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()


        # A button frame
        frame2 = Frame(window)
        frame2.pack()
        displayBtn = Button(frame2, text = "Display", command = self.display)
        displayBtn.pack()

        window.mainloop()

    def display(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            self.canvas.delete("circle")  # delete references to the old circle
            self.x1 = random.randrange(150)
            self.y1 = random.randrange(200)
            self.x2 = self.x1 + 5
            self.y2 = self.y1 + 5
            self.coords = self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2
            self.canvas.create_oval(self.coords, fill = random.choice(colors), tags = "circle")
        self.canvas.update()


RandomBalls()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time through your loop you are deleting everything you created before, including what you created the previous iteration. Move the delete statement outside of the loop:

```
def display(self):
    self.canvas.delete("circle")
    for i in range(0, 10):
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you sir. That did the trick :) And I think it's about the time that SO places a "Buy a drink" button on the site.